# Is Geomesa indexes are reliable and remain in sync with main table?

Tags: geolocation, geomesa

To create indexes, Geomesa creates multiple tables in HBase. I have a few questions:

1. What Geomesa does to ensure these tables are in sync?
2. What will be the impact on Geomesa query, if the index tables are not in sync?
3. What happens (with write calls) if Geomesa is not able to write one of the index tables?
4. Synchronization between tables are the best effort or Geomesa ensure the availability of data with eventual consistency?

I am planning to use Geomesa with Hbase (backed by S3) combination to store my geospatial data; the data size can grow up to Terabytes to Petabytes.

I am investigating how reliable Geomesa is in terms of synchronization between the primary and index table?

**HBase Tables:**

catalog1
catalog1_node_id_v4 (Main Table)
catalog1_node_z2_geom_v5  (Index Table)
catalog1_node_z3_geom_lastUpdateTime_v6  (Index Table)
catalog1_node_attr_identifier_geom_lastUpdateTime_v8   (Index Table)

**Geomesa Schema**

*geomesa-hbase describe-schema -c catalog1 -f node*

INFO  Describing attributes of feature 'node'

key            | String
 namespace      | String
 identifier     | String  (Attribute indexed)
 versionId      | String
 nodeId         | String
 latitude       | Integer 
 longitude      | Integer 
 lastUpdateTime | Date    (Spatio-temporally indexed)
 tags           | Map
 geom           | Point   (Spatio-temporally indexed) (Spatially indexed)

User data:
  geomesa.index.dtg | lastUpdateTime
  geomesa.indices   | z3:6:3:geom:lastUpdateTime,z2:5:3:geom,id:4:3:,attr:8:3:identifier:geom:lastUpdateTime

Comment: so if I update one record in main table, I also have to update all index tables manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoMesa does not do anything to sync indices - generally this should be taken care of in your ingest pipeline.

If you have a reliable feature ID tied to a given input feature, then you can write that feature multiple times without causing duplicates. During ingest, if a batch of features fails due to a transient issue, then you can just re-write them to ensure that the indices are correct.

For HBase, when you call `flush` or `close` on a feature writer, the pending mutations will be sent to the cluster. Once that method returns successfully, then the data has been persisted to HBase. If an exception is thrown, you should re-try the failed features.  If there are subsequent HBase failures, you may need to recover write-ahead logs (WALs) as per standard HBase operation.

A feature may also fail to be written due to validation (e.g. a null geometry). In this case, you would not want to re-try the feature as it will never ingest successfully. If you are using the GeoMesa converter framework, you can [pre-validate](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/convert/parsing_and_validation.html#validators) features to ensure that they will ingest ok.

If you do not have an ingest pipeline already, you may want to check out [geomesa-nifi](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-quickstart-nifi.html), which will let you convert and validate input data, and re-try failures automatically through Nifi flows.

Comment: Thanks Emillio for the explanation. What exception Geomesa throw when it fails to write different index tables? Do you have any document about lis of exception which geomesa throws?

Comment: If it's a validation error it will generally be an `IllegalArgumentException`. If there's an error writing to HBase it will be whatever exception the HBase client throws.

Comment: Based on your response, I assume, when Geomesa try to insert the data into index table (e.g. catalog1_node_z3_geom_lastUpdateTime_v6), and it fails then Geomesa will throw the Hbase exception even though it has saved the data in other indexed table and main table successfully. **Is this understanding correct?**

Comment: Yes, that's why you should re-try failed writes - that will guarantee eventual consistency.

Comment: so if I update one record in main table, I also have to update all index tables manually ?

Comment: No, if you use the API to do the update then it will update all the index tables for you.